# Change Label for an Excel Button

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to add a button in Excel using C#.  I have the button added with the code below:

```
Shape rpsImportButton = worksheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(XlFormControl.xlButtonControl, 700, 35, 150, 22);
rpsImportButton.Name = "Genrate RPS Import Template";
```

The problem I am having is that the label on the button just appears as "Button 2".  the `.Name` attribute does not set the label.  My question is, how do I set the button's label?  I would think this is an easy problem, and I am just missing something small.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the .Caption property.  The .Name property (at least in VBA), is how you would refer to the button in code.

Comment: I am not seeing the .Caption property listed, @RonRosenfeld

Comment: If trying to access the .Caption property this way causes an error message, maybe it is a property of the class to which the button belongs.  Sorry I don't know more about C#, but the .Caption property clearly exists in VBA as I use it frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that took me for ever to get right, and many, many of the answers I tried and found through out the internet didn't help AT ALL.  Solution:

```
Excel.Shape ButtonXX = ws.Shapes.AddFormControl(Excel.XlFormControl.xlButtonControl, 700, 35, 150, 22);
ButtonXX.OLEFormat.Object.Text = "Text I Want";
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
   // make sure that 'worksheet' is dynamic
   dynamic rpsImportButton = worksheet.Butons.Add(700, 35, 150, 22);
   rpsImportButton.Text = "Genrate RPS Import Template";
```

**EDIT:**
Replaced `worksheet.Shapes.AddFormControl` by `worksheet.Buttons.Add`

Comment: .Text or .Label would throw an error saying that they are not valid properties.

Comment: Please check the revised answer.  I replaced `worksheet.Shapes` by `worksheet.Buttons`.